# Express Router .delete returns 404 Not Found?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, methods

Encountered a strange issue while using delete method in Express app.

Here is my app.js document. I am using elevatorRouter for "/elevators" routes.

**app.js**

```
app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/passwordgenerator", passwordgeneratorRouter);
app.use("/elevators", elevatorRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my route file. I am including the elevator router from app.js. It seems that edit route is working fine. I have only issue with "delete" method.

**elevators.js**

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();
const Elevator = require("../models/elevator");
const middleware = require("../middleware");

// Edit Elevator Route
router.get("/:id/edit", (req, res) => {
  Elevator.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundElevator) => {
    res.render("elevators/edit", { elevator: foundElevator });
  });
});

// Delete Elevator Route
router.delete("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Elevator.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/elevators");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/elevators");
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my views. I didnt completely post the entire html. Instead, I have copied partially. I beleive this will be enough. I used postman to send "POST" method directly but still receiving the same 404 error. I beleive it is not related to the view

**view**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="<%= elevator.image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title"><%= elevator.projectName%></h4>
        <p><%= elevator.projectNumber %></p>
        <% if(user) { %>
        <form
          class="delete-form"
          action="/elevators/<%= elevator._id %>?_method=DELETE"
          method="post"
        >
          <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <% } %>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="/elevators" class="btn btn-light float-right">Back</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get response from a DELETE route with a POST HTTP request. It is a well-known issue of browsers, but HTML forms can only send FormData via POST and DELETE is not compatible.
Therefore, Express routing does not match and says POST:“/:id” route does not exist.
Try changing `.delete` to `.post` and it will work.

Edit: There is a method-overwrite module to convert POST requests to DELETE via a query param `_method` (or any other name you choose).

Comment: I am using a method override by "?_method=DELETE". I beleive this is a trick to overcome the challange you mentioned in forms.

Comment: Which is ignored anyway. As long as you’re sending a POST HTTP request, query parameters cannot be sent since they belong to GET HTTP requests. And even if they were sent, they probably would do nothing. Express, as far as I know, does not look for `_method` query parameter to dispatch routes.

Comment: My mistake, having a doubt, I searched and saw it is possible to combine both query string (in the action URL) and POST FormData; I always thought that not. But that does not change the way Express would treat it. And there effectively is the method-override module but it does not appear in your code. Did you required it?

Comment: I have found many examples using the method in Express app. As you suggested, using "post" method solved the issue. However, I wanted to find out what is preventing me from implementing the ways in the examples. Thanks for your advice anyway.

Comment: I didn’t know the existence of this module up to now but it looks great. However, your exemple of code does not contain `app.use(require('method-override')('_method'))`. Do you have that line in your code? See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override

Comment: thank you very much for your help. After installing method_override package, the problem is solved. Thank you...